# Android Studio: How do I install Socrata's Soda 2.0 API for Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, socrata, soda

How do I install this API (https://github.com/socrata/soda-java) in order to use it in an Android project? This seems to be a "left to the student as an exercise" hole in their documentation, while all the usages of the various objects in the API are well-documented and exampled in the readme.md

The one video I could find (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G27zMPLZm6o) was on Mac using a jar. But this API is published in a Zip, which I can paste under app\libs but 'Add as library' won't show up in the right-click menu from there.

The readme hints that:
soda-java is published to Maven Central. The dependency is

(dependency)

```
(groupId)com.socrata(/groupId)

(artifactId)soda-api-java(/artifactId)

(version)0.9.12(/version)
```

(/dependency)

Note: all those parens are actually > and <, and the text is indented, none of which showed up when I pasted it here as it is in the readme.

But I have no idea what that means? I don't know where Maven fits in the world. Am I calling out from my project, like a gem in Ruby? But the video has me copying the actual Zip file locally and installing it in my project. (Git wanted to know if I wanted to include tracking that Zip.)

Answer (score 1):

Morrison's comments about the issues with Jersey and Android aside, there's a release in Github available as a pre-compiled JAR file, I'd start with that:

https://github.com/socrata/soda-java/releases/tag/v0.9.12

There's also the `soda-android` library as well, which might be more appropriate:

https://github.com/socrata/soda-android-sdk

Comment: Yes, I found the Android version after you mentioned it here. And figured out where the .jar was, _in_ the ZIP fiie (>duh<) rather than trying to use the ZIP itself.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to port it.

A quick look at the source here: https://github.com/socrata/soda-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/socrata/api/HttpLowLevel.java

and this line shows that Socrata is using the Jersey project:

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
```

A bit of searching and it appears to be the 1.x version of Jersey and the only thing that I could find related to Android and Jersey is this blog entry with the author trying to get Jersey 2.16 working on Android:
https://blogs.oracle.com/japod/entry/jersey_2_x_client_on

To be clear I've never used these libraries so I have no I idea how hard it would be to port over and made to work on Android as Android Java isn't exactly the same as Oracle/Sun J2SE Java (missing packages, etc.).